# How can I create an x,y curve from an edge?

Tags: matlab, plot, equation, curve, edge-detection

I wanna explain my problem with MATLAB. My objective is to obtain a free liquid surface in a tank from a photo and to do this I have used this algorithm:

```
A = 'C:\foto\img3.bmp';
B = imread(A, 'bmp');
figure(1), imshow(B);
C = rgb2gray(B);
level = graythresh(C);
bw = im2bw(C,level);
bw = bwareaopen(bw, 50);
figure, imshow(bw);
BW1 = edge(bw,'canny');
figure(2), imshow(BW1);
imwrite(BW1, 'C:\foto\im1_edge.bmp', 'bmp')
```

Now I have the surface edge in white, with the background in black.
Next I have also detected the position of only white pixels:

```
I= imread('C:\foto\img3_edge.bmp');
imshow(I);
[r c] =size(I);
for j=1:c
  for i=1:r
   if(I(i,j)==1)                  
   [i j]
   end
  end
end
```

At this point, how can I report (with a macro, automatically possibly) each couple of coordinates on a cartesian (x,y) plane? My objective is to obtain from the edge, so reconstructed, a function of the type "y = f(x)".
I have tried with another edge and have modified with paint the image to delete all useless pixels, the example is this one:

[image]

with the code:

```
 I = im2bw(I);
```

it returns me an error "Warning: The input image is already binary." Next using the code:

```
 [r c] = find(I), output = [r c];
 plot(r,c,'.')
```

I obtained this one:

[image: Image2]

Moreover, when I try to insert r as xdata and c as ydata in cftool, I obtain the same problem and when I use "Interpolant" fitting, it returns an error. Why?

Comment: Use a `polynomial` fitting for this type of curve

Comment: You can simplify your detections of white points: Instead of the two for loops use: *[row col] = find(I==1)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what type of fit you want to apply to your data. The following code will fit a 3rd order polynomial on your data.

```
I = imread('20jh1g2.jpg');
I = im2bw(I);
imshow(I);

[r, c] = find(I);
figure;
plot(c,r,'.');
hold on;
f = fit(c, r, 'poly3');
plot((min(c):max(c)),f(min(c):max(c)), 'red', 'LineWidth', 3);
```

Which will produce:

[image: 3rd order polynomial fit]

The rotation can be explained by how the axis are defined. In your image the Y axis goes from 0 at the top to 374 at the bottom. You can transform the result of your fit back into a binary image with the following code;

```
x = (min(c):max(c))';
y = round(f(x));
I = zeros(size(I));
I(y +((x-1)*size(I,1))) = 1;
figure
imshow(I);
```

Which will produce:

[image: binary image of fit]

The result of the fit, `f` is stored in a `cfit` object. You can evaluate this function by feeding it values for `x`, as shown above. The function coefficients can be found by printing the fields of the `cfit` object in the command window;

```
f = 

     Linear model Poly3:
     f(x) = p1*x^3 + p2*x^2 + p3*x + p4
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p1 =  -6.252e-06  (-6.542e-06, -5.963e-06)
       p2 =    0.001753  (0.001588, 0.001918)
       p3 =     -0.3667  (-0.3932, -0.3401)
       p4 =       290.4  (289.3, 291.6)
```

To flip the function inside your reference frame and compute the centroid you can use this;

```
I = imread('20jh1g2.jpg');
I = im2bw(I);

[r, c] = find(I);
r = -r + size(I,1);
f = polyfit(c, r, 3);
plot((min(c):max(c)),polyval(f,(min(c):max(c))), 'red', 'LineWidth', 3);
hold on;

xf = [f 0];
fx2 = sym2poly(poly2sym(f)^2);
centroid = 1/polyval(polyint(f),size(I,2)) * [polyval(polyint(xf),size(I,2)) 1/2 * polyval(polyint(fx2),size(I,2))];
plot(centroid(1),centroid(2),'X');
```

Which will produce:

[image: 3rd order polynomial fit with centroid]

Comment: Thanks for the help @0xMB, this result is a good point! But how can I set the rotated curve definitively? Because if I use **plot(f)** the curve results rotated yet. Moreover, can I detect the centroid of mass for the area under the curve?

Comment: Firefly, can you please explain a bit more in depth what you are trying to achieve? Why do you want to plot the fit? It shouldn't matter how you plot the fit, since the relation between x and y is the same. Finding the centroid of mass for the area under the curve is simple maths once you obtain the coefficients of your polynomial.

Comment: 0xMB sorry for my bad English, probably I have not explained well. My objective is to compare 2 water free-surface: 1 from an experimental test (photo) and the other 1 from a simulation with the programs Fluent (or Flow3D). I want to obtain only the 2 curves (without the rest of the image), so I can compare them, set the coordinates (x,y) in Meters (lengths of the tank) and verify the error percentage resulted by the simulation with Fluent. Next I want obtain also the centroid of mass for each time step in a transient simulation, so I can draw a curve passing through all these points

Comment: 0xMB this is great! My first task is accomplished :). Now I want to ask you another problem: if my surface is more complex than the previous example, after detected the edge with the "canny" code, how can I obtain a "more real" curve? Because the polynomial fit is perfect if the surface is linear...but if there are more waves, is there a more precise function?

Comment: I have no knowledge about water surfaces, but you can simply try to fit other functions on your data and determine the goodness of the fit to evaluate which type of function is best for describing your data. Take a look here to figure out which function types MATLAB supports: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/curvefit/list-of-library-models-for-curve-and-surface-fitting.html#btbcvnl